# VBA runtime error 9

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am currently getting a error saying subscript out of range. on the line of code

```
If Sheets(Master).Cells(i, A).Value = AssetNum.Value Then
```

I'm trying to use a for loop to increment i so the row range starts at 12 and adds 1 to it each time. Then inside the for loop I want to use an If statement to check and see if the cell (i,A) is equal to the value in AssetNum. If the loop reaches the value of the EmptyRow it ends the loop. Im not exactly sure how to use a for loop IF-THen statement correctly.

```
Public i As Integer

Private Sub AssetNum_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub Enter_Click()



Dim EmptyRow As Long

'Audit will only search Master Sheet
Worksheets("Master").Activate


'Find empty row value so we can use that for limit of search
With Sheets("Master")
     EmptyRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With

'i needs to be set to minimum limit
'Begin loop of search
For i = 12 To EmptyRow + 1

If Cells(i, 1).Value = AssetNum.Value Then

    'Go to compare userform to display

    Compare.AssetDisplay.Value = AssetNum.Value
    Compare.LocationDisply.Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
    Compare.Show

   End If
 Next i

    'If i gets to emptyrow num then go to non found asset userform
    Unload Me
    NonFoundAsset.Show
```

Comment: Please post your real code (one that compiles, and that matches the first fragment in your question)

Comment: You didn't get the line of code you are talking about into your question.  If Sheets(Master).Cells(i, A).Value = AssetNum.Value Then Is not in the code you posted.

Comment: I apologize  I had changed it to try another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your refer with your error to the line:

```
If Cells(i, A).Value = AssetNum.Value Then
```

Well, I see nowhere that `A` is declared. Then VBA declares it automatically (advice: *always* turn Tools, Options, Require variable declarations to **ON**). Neither do I see `A` being initialized, so its value will be `0` and that is not a valid reference for `Cells`. Hence, Subscript out of bounds.

If you want to reference the "A" column, then write:

```
If Cells(i, 1).Value = AssetNum.Value Then
```

as "A" is the first column.

Comment: I was trying to use 'a" as just the Column A

Comment: If you would had turnd on _Tools, Options, Require variable declarations_ then VBA would have given you an error that A is not declared and you would have known you were doing something wrong here...

Comment: I now have that turned on, Thank You i was unaware I could do that

Comment: Fine, glad to be of help. Please accept the answer by clicking on the number on the left of my answer.

Comment: I had updated my for loop, Its running correctly now except when I am trying to do my If statement the "AssetNum.Value" is not being read in to be checked. If i manually put in what I am looking for everything will work properly though however. I'm not sure why it is not reading in the value, any thoughts?

Comment: the AssetNum.Value is a textbox value in a userform

Comment: Try the `Text` property. The ` Value` property is set later (after Enter, or Loose Focus).

Answer (score 0):

Use as follow:

```
If Sheets(Master).Cells(i, "A").Value = AssetNum.Value Then
```

And also this line:

```
Compare.LocationDisply.Value = Cells(i, "B").Value
```